# How to get path inside folder project in java spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I try to make web apps using java spring MVC.

I set my project folder on D: and the tomcat on C:.

I want to set the path folder for the upload purpose using this code :

```
String absoluteFilePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/uploads/");
```

but the file always set on tomcat, not on project folder. please help me

Comment: do u mean u want to use an external web server? and u din't want to use the tomcat on ur IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Your Context is always set where your project is deployed thats the reason it is always set on Tomcat. if you want to set any other folder then please use Java File Handling. For Taking Path Dynamically you can use Java Environment Variable as well.

Comment: can you give me any reference ?

Comment: So basically Java Has System.getEnv() method. Which is used to get Environment Variable. You can use that. And you can set any environment variable for that purpose.